# Can you get something like Unity Dash--especially the instant calculator--in other distros?

Tags: ubuntu, unity, calculator

In Ubuntu, Unity Dash is a lot like the Mac Spotlight: a search interface, app launcher, and, with the calculator lens (https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-scope-calculator/), an instant calculator:
[image]

I *really* like this a lot. Is there any way to get the same functionality--especially the instant calculator-- in other distros that don't use Unity, which I'm otherwise ambivalent about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnome launcher is very similar to Unity launcher: search files and folders, launch app, make calculation.
I don't know if KDE as something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question because I found something else suitable in addition to what Ubalot said: https://github.com/qdore/Mutate